# cron.daily midnight download

Tags: cron

I run a headless Pi in a weather station using cellular data. Every night after midnight it does an 8MB download - I don't know what it is, but that's what vnstat tells me. Being as how the system runs on cellular I'd like to kill that.

Had a look in /etc/cron.daily and found a script called apt. It seems to call apt-get update which coincidentally downloads about 8MB...
 when I run it manually. I am not keen to hack the script because it has lots of variables and parameters and ifs and stuff. Life would get a bit ugly if I kill the system.

So I am leaning towards just getting rid of the script altogether. Perhaps someone knows something about this? I am using DietPi

Answer (score 1):

**There is no need to have a cron job running apt-get update on a regular basis.  You can remove that job safely**

Just running it manually should be enough.

My recommendation is that it be run before any new software is installed.

Then afterwards, you might want to run apt-get check to look for interdependencies, but it rarely finds anything.

If it finds something amiss, you can run apt-get autoremove to clean things up.

Before any of this, it is always a good idea to do a full shutdown.
Give it a minute or two for the green light to stop.
Then pull the SD card and put it in an adapter and install in your PC,
then use Win32DiskImager to take a snapshot of your system just in case you need to restore it back to the way it is before you start changing things.